# Does it make sense to say "it makes someone no longer trust you"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm trying to write a paragraph and I need to write a sentence similar to the sentence below:

> Your audience won't trust you any more if you lie, and it only ruins your reputation.

And the sentence below is the one i'v just written. I'd like to know if the last part of my sentence delivers the same meaning of "Your audience won't trust you any more" in the above sentence.

> If you lie, it only ruins your reputation and **makes your audience no longer trust you**.

Comment: What is about the sentence that makes you doubt its correctness?  I know you highlighted the part you want reviewed, but what is the specific grammatical construction  or word choice that you find unclear?

Comment: Agree with @Vegawatcher, at the moment this question is off-topic as you have not presented any research or asked a question about understanding language. Asking to check if something is right or wrong is not a valid question for this site. Voting to close, but will happily retract if you can add something to it.

Comment: I've just edited my question, sorry for unclear question.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote has the same meaning, although some people may prefer "Lying only ruins . . ."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: @vahid as the comments have said, they way you wrote it has the same meaning, but I would prefer "if you lie, you will loose the trust of your audience." or "if you lie, your audience will no longer trust you." I also like "Lying only ruins" as marc suggests.